# How can I find callers to a function/macro?

Tags: search

Given an elisp function or macro, does Emacs provide any way of finding callers?

Currently I'm just grepping in `~/.emacs.d` for examples, but it's crude. Slime has `slime-who-references` but the excellent `elisp-slime-nav` doesn't seem to have an equivalent command.

Comment: Finding callers where? What context do you want to search? The problem is not defined sufficiently.

Comment: https://github.com/vapniks/simple-call-tree may be of interest

Comment: @Drew ideally callers anywhere in the code loaded in my current Emacs instance.

Comment: `load-history` tells you what the explicitly loaded libraries are. You can search (`grep` or otherwise) those libraries. (But my crystal ball whispers to me that there is a question behind your question as posed. Why do you want to find all callers?)

Comment: @Drew: When looking at an unfamiliar function/macro, I want to see some examples of it being used. This helps me understand whether I'm using it correctly.

Comment: I see. In that case, I'd suggest: (1) For 3rd-party libraries, use `C-h f` and (click the link in `*Help*` to) go to the file that defines it, as a start. It is likely that there are examples there, and if not, you can `grep` just that directory. For core Emacs libraries, `grep` the source directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a package that does this! [refs.el, semantic search for elisp](https://github.com/Wilfred/refs.el).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's even possible. Elisp has dynamic scope, any symbol can be rebound to anything (and it is being used and abused as you know.) So nothing is known statically.

I do the same, I mean grepping. I use `silver-searcher` and `helm` variations a lot around it, including `helm-swoop` to make the grepping more palatable, and I am always on a lookout for ways to improve it, but I guess at the fundamental level text/regexp search is what we have to deal with.

Comment: That's right.  For example, I have calls to a number of built ins in my init file.  How is anything you run on _your_ machine going to know that?

Comment: Increasing elisp packages are using lexical scope. A simple implementation that called `read` would be smarter than grepping though, as it wouldn't confuse `foo-bar` with `foo`, or strings/comments.

Comment: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/el-search.html